# Player won't move correctly due to gravity force pushing him into the ground

Tags: collision-detection, python, pygame

I am making a tilemap platformer with pygame ad I defined the X and Y movement for the player and also a Y force that represents the gravity force to make it jump correctly. However, when my player falls off to the ground and the game begins, it doesn't move correctly neither to the right nor to the left direction due to the gravity force that keeps pushing him to the down. In addition to that, when the player jumps and i move it to the right, it's like it doesn't recognize the collision with the bottom rect of the wall (see gif below for a visual explanation of that).

I tried disabling that gravity force when the player hits the ground and enable it when the player jumps but it didn't work as expected and I've got problems managing collisions (also, it doesn't make sense to disable gravity, right?)

Here's a gif of the issue i'm facing with:
[image]

Here's my Player class:

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def **init**(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.**init**(self, self.groups)

```
    self.game = game

    self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
    self.image.fill(GREEN)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    self.move_left = self.move_right = False

    self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(x, y)
    self.acc = pg.math.Vector2(0, GRAVITY)
    self.vel = pg.math.Vector2(0, 0)

def jump(self):
    self.vel.y -= 3

def update(self):
    self.vel.x = 0

    if self.move_left:
        self.vel.x = -PLAYER_SPEED
    if self.move_right:
        self.vel.x = PLAYER_SPEED

    self.vel += self.acc

    self.pos += self.vel
    self.rect.x = self.pos.x * TILESIZE
    self.rect.y = self.pos.y * TILESIZE

    if self.vel.y > 0.5:
        self.vel.y = 0.5

    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
    if hits:
        if self.vel.x > 0:
            self.pos -= self.vel
            self.rect.right = hits[0].rect.left
            self.vel.x = 0
        if self.vel.x < 0:
            self.pos -= self.vel
            self.rect.left = hits[0].rect.right
            self.vel.x = 0

    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
    if hits:
        if self.vel.y > 0:
            self.pos -= self.vel
            self.rect.bottom = hits[0].rect.top
            self.vel.y = 0
        if self.vel.y < 0:
            self.pos -= self.vel
            self.rect.top = hits[0].rect.bottom
            self.vel.y = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to assume the player will only collide with walls when it is moving to the side. I think this assumption causes the shaky sliding as the player also collides with the floor whenever it walks. You may want to rename your `game.walls` to something like `game.obstacles` to reduce the chance of confusing yourself. ツ

Comment: That's a good suggestion, however I know the player collides with the floor everytime he wallks (I also made some prints to make sure it worked as expected in this meaning) but I do not understood how this may be related to my problem.

Comment: `self.pos -= self.vel` moves the player back, even if it only collides with the floor.